# float object not iterable in print statement for list -python

Tags: python, list, iterable

Any help much appreciated. I have lists in a program, one containing the values of the linear function approximation for various values of X. The other containing the residuals of these points to the actual y values. The lists are defined the same way within the respected functions, and the print statements are the same. Yet for the residual print statement, I keep getting the error: float object is not iterable.

I don't get why this is or why this object is any different from the one defined in the linear function.

Here is some code:

```
final_values = []
def y_strength(X):
    for x in X:
        f = (m * x) + b
        global final_values 
        final_values.append(f)
    return final_values 

final_values = y_strength(X)        

strength = []
final_r = []
def r_strength(Y):
    global strength
    for y in Y:
        r = y - lin_funct
        strength.append(r)

    for r in strength:
        r = r ** 2
        final_r.append(r)

    relationship = sum(final_r)   
    return relationship
strength = r_strength(Y)

def(print()):
     print("f(x):","\t".join(str(round(float(c),2)) for c in final_values))
     print("-"*70)
     print("R:   ","\t".join(str(round(float(c),2)) for c in strength))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `print()` call, you have `for c in final_values`. This reference comes from a call to `y_strength`, which assembles and returns a `list`. This can be iterated over.

In the second `print()` call, you have `for c in strength`. This reference comes from a call to `r_strength`, which calculates and returns a sum, which is a number. This cannot be iterated over.

To fix this, simply don't iterate over it:

```
print("R:   ", round(strength, 2))
```

Comment: sorry new to whole site I don't know how to get the code, but I just separated the r_strength function into two different functions. one for strength and one for final_r

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing your `strength` value which is initially a list with the `sum` of another list (via the function's return value).

I'm not actually sure why you're using global variables at all, you could just move the initial definitions inside the functions, since you're already returning the list and assigning it over the previous reference.

Comment: There are other functions in the program using them. Also if not global then I have come across many issues with recognizing it in print statement. It works with global